# Not able to move the form fields while creating wpf application in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am currently using visual studio 2010 and i want to create a simple WPF application. I want to know why I am not able to move the form fields. I am able to resize the fields but not move them. I am new to this and I have no clue about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Margins of your form fields and they will move. They are in the form of "left,top,right,bottom".